# ASP.NET Authentication | .NET Framework | .NET Core | Side by Side | Angular

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework/Angular) and a ASP.NET Core Web Application (Angular). They should run side-by-side. I would like to use the same Identity Database. But it seems that there are different password hasher used. Can I change ASP.NET Core Web Application (Angular) to use the same as ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework/Angular) password hasher?

I already updated the database as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers ADD
   ConcurrencyStamp VARCHAR(255) NULL,
   LockoutEnd DATETIME NULL,
  NormalizedEmail VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  NormalizedUserName VARCHAR(255) NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE ASPNETROLES ADD
   ConcurrencyStamp VARCHAR(255) NULL,
   NormalizedName VARCHAR(255) NULL;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory](
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MigrationId] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId] ,[ProductVersion]) VALUES ('00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema','3.0.0')
GO
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) about storing security keys.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys\"));
}
```

Create a key or let the applicaiton create the key, and share it between the 2 applications using this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to get the desired functionality:

Add the following to Startup.cs (.NET Core projects):

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
```

Migrate the database and update the data:

```
UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET NormalizedUserName = UPPER(UserName);
```

For more details see here: https://github.com/iwhp/AspNetIdentitySideBySide